# Add speed to scroll with mousewheel

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

Im using jScrollpane Plugin to scroll content in div.

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

When i scroll content using mousewheel, the speed is very slowly and the normal scroll (no plugin) is very fast. This is a problem to the users :(

Can i setup this?

Actually i've this config:

```
        $(function()
        {
            $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane(
                {
                    verticalDragMinHeight: 200,
                    verticalDragMaxHeight: 200,
                    horizontalDragMinWidth: 200,
                    horizontalDragMaxWidth: 200
                }
            );
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit hard to find but you can set the speed (`mouseWheelSpeed`) in your config as well:

```
$(function(){
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({
        verticalDragMinHeight: 200,
        verticalDragMaxHeight: 200,
        horizontalDragMinWidth: 200,
        horizontalDragMaxWidth: 200,
        mouseWheelSpeed: 3
    });
});
```

Where `3` is the default. Play with that value to see when it has the correct speed.